# Visual studio code html suggestion not working

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code

```
body{
    background-image:url(asd.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: ;
}
```

after i write `background-po` ,it suggests `background-position:`

I press 'Enter', but then it no longer suggests `background-position` to me. What could I do next without pressing `CTRL` + `Space`, can anyone tell me how it can do this automatically please?

I'm learning HTML & CSS and these suggestions will help me a lot

Comment: Was implemented in 1.19

Answer (score 0):

To add to [dippas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3448527/dippas)' answer, you can also use keywords together, like `top left`, or `center center` for example.

To get the prompt from your code-editor (this depends on the code editor though), when it suggests `background-position`, press the 'End' key or Tab key BEFORE pressing return (on a windows keyboard).

I hope this helps, but I agree with dippas, you should get to know the allowed values, it will save you time in the long run.

Comment: For Vscode consider installing this css-autocomplete extension https://github.com/ecmel/vscode-html-css

Comment: I tried what you said,but tab key only does the same as return key it doesn't autosuggest the allowed values after background-position (end key does nothing),the extension also doesn't do the thing i still need the ctrl+space.

Comment: @Tornnado did you install the extension? The link was posted because it the extension is specifically designed for vscode for css autocompletion

Answer (score 0):

I work on VS Code, and what you describe seems like a poor user experience to me. We should automatically show value suggestions after you accept a property name suggestion.

I've opened [an issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/31948) to track this.